# How do i implement 2 way SSL authentication in C# Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a new ASP.net Web API. I already have a SSL certificate for the server on which this API is going to be hosted. How do i implement authentication using 2 way SSL?
It will be really helpful if someone can provide a sample code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

To set SSL connection you need to:

1. Set 'SSL Enabled' on true in 'Project Properties'.
2. Write SLL URL address into 'Project URL' in 'WEB' part of 'Properties'.
3. Before your API class you need to put [RequireHttps] tag.

I hope you will play with that without example code :)